# module issues with kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules, arch-arm

I am currently getting this error message:-

> iptables v1.4.12: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
>   Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

I have tried insmod, updating the kernel from apt-get but I am really at a loss they are just not working and I have no idea why. what should I do? recompile the kernel? when I was installing the modules when first installing the kernel all IPV4 related modules failed to install. help me people of the internet!

I am using -> Linaro 14.04 (GNU/Linux 3.15.0+ armv7l)

> apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)

I have already tried the above and update everything I still get the same error and I try running this again and it tells me everything is upto date (yes I did update the apts)

edit -- some information from dmesg

> [   60.551189] init: tty1 main process (1534) killed by TERM signal
>
> [   65.094650] init: lxdm main process (1463) terminated with status 1
>
> [  182.391322] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_free_table_info (err 0)
>
> [  182.391378] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_alloc_table_info (err 0)
>
> [  182.391422] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_check_match (err 0)
>
> [  182.391467] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_request_find_target (err
>   0)
>
> [  182.391497] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_unregister_matches (err 0)
>
> [  182.391534] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_request_find_match (err 0)
>
> [  182.391584] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_unregister_targets (err 0)
>
> [  182.391606] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_recseq (err 0)
>
> [  182.391701] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_register_targets (err 0)
>
> [  182.391798] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_register_table (err 0)
>
> [  182.391819] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_proto_init (err 0)
>
> [  182.391855] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_replace_table (err 0)
>
> [  182.391882] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_find_table_lock (err 0)
>
> [  182.391925] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_table_unlock (err 0)
>
> [  182.391945] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_proto_fini (err 0)
>
> [  182.391964] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_register_matches (err 0)
>
> [  182.391984] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_check_target (err 0)
>
> [  182.392018] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_find_revision (err 0)
>
> [  182.392045] ip_tables: Unknown symbol xt_unregister_table (err 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in the end, I recompiled the kernel, recopied over the modules and created a symlink between 3.15.0 to 3.15.0+ ... this + was not added to a file for some reason which messed up alot of things adding this I was able to make and install modules